# IP Routing - Multiple Interfaces

Tags: centos, networking, iptables, routing, iproute

I am using Elastix 2.5 (CentOS 5.11) with 4 NIC's (1 for WAN and 3 For SIP Trunk using IP Authentication)

```
eth0 - WAN
IPADDR=75.XX.XX.162
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
GATEWAY=75.XX.XX.161

eth1 - SIP TRUNK1
IPADDR=100.XX.XX.198
NETMASK=255.255.255.252
GATEWAY=100.XX.XX.197

eth2 - SIP TRUNK2
IPADDR=100.XX.XX.194
NETMASK=255.255.255.252
GATEWAY=100.XX.XX.193

eth3 - SIP TRUNK3
IPADDR=100.XX.XX.186
NETMASK=255.255.255.252
GATEWAY=100.XX.XX.185
```

all the SIP trunk has to pass the calls 100.XX.XX.5 for authentication & 100.XX.XX.4 for media

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
100.XX.XX.5     100.XX.XX.193   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth2
100.XX.XX.5     100.XX.XX.185   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth3
100.XX.XX.5     100.XX.XX.197   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth1
100.XX.XX.4     100.XX.XX.193   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth2
100.XX.XX.4     100.XX.XX.185   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth3
100.XX.XX.4     100.XX.XX.197   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth1
100.XX.XX.184   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 eth3
100.XX.XX.192   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 eth2
100.XX.XX.196   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 eth1
75.XX.XX.160    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         75.XX.XX.161    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth3
```

All the SIP Trunks (eth1, eth2, eth3) has maximum capacity of 200 Channels

with the above routes all the calls is passing through eth2 100.XX.XX.193, So i able to achieve 200 CC only

Kindly help to route all the traffic to

```
100.XX.XX.5 & 100.XX.XX.4
```

via all the SIP Trunk GW's below

```
eth1 100.XX.XX.197 
eth2 100.XX.XX.193
eth3 100.XX.XX.185
```

Comment: this question is cross-posted ( https://serverfault.com/questions/1009945/ip-routing-multiple-interfaces ). You should keep only one of them and delete the other.

Comment: Also, is the SIP software able to choose a source IP (eg: in a round-robin way or some load evaluation mechanism)? It must bind the UDP socket before sending a packet to the backend for an answer based on advanced routing to be useful.